# Meaning of "soft and warm" when refers to a person

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

I'm doing a translation from english and I'm struggling to understand the first part of the sentence:

"She’s soft and warm, unmistakably alive."

Context: her boyfriend thought she was dead, but it turns out she's not.

I've done some research and I've just found that "soft and warm" is used to describe people, mainly asian, with a cute and fluffy face, but I don't think that's the case. In this context, I guess it emphasizes the idea that she is alive: her body is still warm, but I don't fully understand the use of "soft" here.

If someone could help me out, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the context, this seems to be a purely literal description - she's still soft, i.e. rigor mortis has not set in as it would for a dead person. You're right that "soft and warm" can often be metaphorical, referring to a person's disposition, but this doesn't seem to be one of those cases. Soft as in the opposite of stiff; warm as in the opposite of cold.